# nullif not working

Tags: sql, oracle

My nullif doesnt seem to be working when v2 is null, do I have this right?

`SELECT ROUND (v1 / NULLIF (v2, 0), 3)
  FROM t1
 WHERE id = 100`

for eg: when V1=58 and V2 is null, the result should be 58 but its returning null.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `NULLIF()` and `COALESCE()`.  Your expression is correct for preventing divide-by-zero.  It is exactly the right thing to use in this situation, and it is working correctly.

If you want to treat a `NULL` value as `1`, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(v1 / (CASE WHEN v2 IS NULL THEN 1
                        WHEN v2 <> 0 THEN v2
                   END), 3)
FROM t1
WHERE id = 100;
```

That seems like odd logic to me.

Comment: This would be a bit better methinks if it dealt with v2 = 0 situations as well.

Comment: @Alan . . . It does.  The `case` returns `NULL` if none of the conditions match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I am confused, my V1 is age field and V2 is the multiplication factor for age unit to convert into years. When V1 is in years, V2 is blank. So in my example, wouldn't nullif return null? If so, shouldn't the result be 58?

Comment: @Skn . . . Anything times `NULL` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT ROUND (v1/ COALESCE(v2,1), 3)
FROM FROM t1 
WHERE id = 100;
```